# Loop through rows of a query in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL script:

```
declare @Name nvarchar

declare data cursor for
select Name from MyDB.dbo.MyTable;

OPEN data;  

-- Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM data;  

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  

   FETCH NEXT FROM data INTO @Name;  
   Print 'Name: ' + @Name
END  
CLOSE data;  
DEALLOCATE data;  
GO
```

I want to make a script that will compare each of the strings in a first column with each of the strings in the second column.

The problem is, I don't know how to loop through each of the rows and take a separate string value.
The code above prints only the first value in the query result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your first fetch next doesn't have an `into`; your `@Name` variable doesn't have a length (so is only 1 char); `fetch next` should be the *last* thing in the while loop.

Comment: @TZHX yes, that is my solution.

Comment: "I want to make a script that will compare each of the strings in a first column with each of the strings in the second column." You can probably do that without a cursor, using cross join or cross apply. If you [edit] your question to include sample data as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language), as well as your desired result, it will make it so much easier to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

To compare all values from one column to all values in another column you don't need a cursor, a simple join will do the work - since you didn't provide sample data and also not desired results, I had to make my own:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Name1 char(3),
    Name2 char(3)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable (Name1, Name2) VALUES
('abc','def'),('zyx','abc'),
('ghi','jkl'),('yza','ghi'),
('mno','pqr'),('nml','mno'),('pqr','qpo'),
('stu','vwx'),('wvu','tsr'),('kji','hgf')
```

The query:

```
SELECT T1.Id, T1.Name1, T1.Name2, T2.Id, T2.Name1, T2.Name2
FROM MyTable T1
JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.Name1 = T2.Name2
```

Result:

```
Id  Name1   Name2   Id  Name1   Name2
1   abc     def     2   zyx     abc
3   ghi     jkl     4   yza     ghi
5   mno     pqr     6   nml     mno
7   pqr     qpo     5   mno     pqr
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use a Cursor.

Are your columns in the same table? If so this is as simple as this;

```
-- Show All rows with [DIFFERENT] Name and Name2 fields
SELECT 
    Name,
    Name2
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE 
    Name <> Name2

-- Show All rows with [SAME] Name and Name2 fields
SELECT 
    Name,
    Name2
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE 
    Name = Name2
```

If not you will need to post the table definitions and names of columns to get a more concrete example