# How to compare each string from first column with each string in second column in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is the code I tried:

```
declare @o1 nvarchar(255)
declare @o2 nvarchar(255)

declare data cursor for
select o1.Name, o2.Name from MyDB.dbo.Table1 as o1, MyDB.dbo.MyTable2 as o2;

OPEN data;  

-- Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM data into @o1, @o2;  

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  

   FETCH NEXT FROM data INTO @o1, @o2;  
   Print 'Name1: ' + @o1

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
       -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  

       FETCH NEXT FROM data INTO @o1, @o2;  
       Print 'Name2: ' + @o2
    END 
END  
CLOSE data;  
DEALLOCATE data;  
GO
```

I am getting two columns in my query and both are nvarchar(255). 
I want to compare each value from the first column with each value of the second column. That can be achieved with loop inside a loop, but I don't know what should I do with the cursor part.

Should I put a variable and keep fetch status separately? 
Or somethings else will do the trick?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Why are you trying to compare the two columns?  You may be able to compare them without using cursors by using a set based query.  Commenting on your code: You fetch twice before `Print 'Name1: ' + @o1`, so the values from the 1st fetch are lost.  Then you fetch again before consuming `@o2`, so the value assigned to `@o2` (just above `... 'Name1:' ...`) is lost.  Then you only consume `@o2` after the last fetch, so `@o1` from the last fetch is also lost.  Also, the query you use for your cursor is a Cartesian Product because you don't join the tables in any way.

Comment: When you use cursors, it is best to `declare` your cursor, then `open`, `fetch`, start your `while @@fetch_status` loop, write code inside the while loop to consume the fetched values, include a single fetch statement just before the end of the `while` loop, `close` and `deallcoate` the cursor.

Comment: As per your description, you don't have to use neither cursor nor loop, the desired result can be achieved by a simple  join query. Provide some sample data so I can give you the final query.

Comment: How is that different from your previous question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through rows of a query in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741414/loop-through-rows-of-a-query-in-t-sql)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes there are similarities. This question was to decide how to compare strings, whether trough a loop or just using regular TSQL command. The other question was for the syntax, what do I miss in my loop inside a loop. But I got the result by using Cross Join and LIKE operator.

Comment: Well, then, you might want to post the solution as a self answer, so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you don't need a cursor you can use select :

```
Select o1, O2
from table1
where o1 in (select o2 from table1)
```